# I am not able to write Test class for below code

Tags: apex, unit-test, test-setup

I am having class which is firing on trigger Before update
Here is the class code

```
public class UpdateAbscenceRecord {
    public static void UpdateAbsenceOnUpdate(Map<id,account> NewAccountMap,Map<id,Account>OldAccountMap){
        set<id>accountIds=new set<id>();
        for(id aid:NewAccountMap.keySet()){
            account newAccount=NewAccountMap.get(aid);
            account oldaccount=OldAccountMap.get(aid);
            if(newAccount.Start_Date__c!=oldAccount.Start_Date__c || newAccount.Expirry_Date__c!=oldAccount.Expirry_Date__c){
                accountids.add(aid);    
            }
            if(accountids!=null && !accountids.isEmpty()){
                list<Absence__c> abscenceList,abscenceToUpdate;
                abscenceList=[select UpdateAcc__c,Wind_Account__c from Absence__c where Wind_Account__c in:accountids];
                if(abscenceList!=null && !abscenceList.isEmpty()){
                    for(Absence__c abs:abscenceList){
                        abs.UpdateAcc__c=true;
                    }
                    update abscenceList; 
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Test class--

```
    @isTest
public class UpdateAbscenceRecord_Test {
    static  testmethod void RunTest(){
        map<id,account> NewAccount=new map<id,Account>();
        Map<id,account>OldAccount=new Map<id,account>();
        set<id>accid=new set<id>();
        account acc=new account(Start_Date__c=system.today(),Expirry_Date__c=system.today(),name='Test Account');
        test.startTest();
        insert acc;
        test.stopTest();
        OldAccount.put(acc.id, acc);
        accid.add(acc.id);
        acc.Start_Date__c=system.today()-12;
        acc.Expirry_Date__c=system.today()-10;
        update acc;     
        NewAccount.put(acc.id, acc);
        Absence__c abs=new Absence__c(UpdateAcc__c=false,Wind_Account__c=acc.id);
        test.startTest();
        insert abs;
        test.stopTest();
        Absence__c   abscenceList=[select UpdateAcc__c,Wind_Account__c from Absence__c where Wind_Account__c =:acc.id];
        abscenceList.UpdateAcc__c=true;
        update abscenceList;
        system.assert(abscenceList!=null);
        system.assertEquals(true, abscenceList.UpdateAcc__c);
    }

}
```

Trigger-

```
trigger AccountExampl on Account (before update) {       UpdateAbscenceRecord.UpdateAbsenceOnUpdate(trigger.newmap,trigger.oldmap);
```

}

Comment: have you tried anything ?

Comment: share your trigger code as well

Comment: above is my test class which is covering 78%....could you please help to enhance the test class with best practice and   below class lines are not getting covered                                                                              for(Absence__c abs:abscenceList){
                        abs.UpdateAcc__c=true;
                    }
                    update abscenceList; 
                }

Answer (score 0):

```
 @isTest
public class UpdateAccountAddresses_Test {

 static  testmethod void runTest(){
        account acc=new account(Start_Date__c=system.today(),Expirry_Date__c=system.today().addDays(10),name='Test Account');
        insert acc; 
        Absence__c abs=new   Absence__c(UpdateAcc__c=false,Wind_Account__c=acc.id);
        insert abs;
        acc.Start_Date__c=system.today().addDays(10);
        acc.Expirry_Date__c=system.today().addDays(10);

        test.startTest();
                update acc;
        test.stopTest();


        System.assertEquals(true, abs.UpdateAcc__c);
}   
}
```